# Installing PythonMagick with boost on osx

Tags: macos, boost, boost-python, pythonmagick

I am trying to install PythonMagick following these instructions. https://gist.github.com/tomekwojcik/2778301

When I get to `$ make` I get this error

```
Making all in pythonmagick_src
CXX      libpymagick_la-_DrawableFillRule.lo
_DrawableFillRule.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'boost/python.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/python.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [libpymagick_la-_DrawableFillRule.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

How do I get PythonMagick installed in my project? Any way that will work. I can't find useful instructions anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have boost-python `brew boost-python`. Note the version number, as you'll need to replace `1.59.0` below with the correct version.

```
$ BOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.59.0
$ ./configure
```

Edit `Makefile` and `pythonmagick_src/Makefile` to include the boost library. You are looking for two lines: `DEFAULT_INCLUDES` and `LDFLAGS`. You'll add boost paths to the end of those lines, making them look something like this:

```
DEFAULT_INCLUDES = -I. -I$(top_builddir)/config -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.59.0/include
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.59.0/lib
```

That should resolve the compile/link errors.